# Eclipse JDT dom refactoring, extract class member from one compilation unit & add into another

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

This is a groovy script that extracts a class member from one compilation unit stores it in a model named Member then attempts to add it to another compilation unit.

I'm having issues with the last part, can anyone help me out. I've been hyperlinking through the jdt javadoc for a while and I can't seem to find the right execution sequence

```
void addMemberToTargetSourceFile(CompilationUnit cu2,  List<Member> memberToBeAddedToTargets){
    cu2.recordModifications();

    for(m in memberToBeAddedToTargets){
        AbstractTypeDeclaration type = (AbstractTypeDeclaration)cu2.types().get(0)
        type.add(m.node.asType( ASTNode.nodeClassForType(m.node.getNodeType()))
    }
    ASTRewrite astRewrite= ASTRewrite.create(cu2.getAST())
    Document doc = new Document(cu2.toString())
    TextEdit edit= astRewrite.rewriteAST(doc, null)
    edit.apply(doc)

    println "${edit.toString()}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done because of the (groovy downside is that without strong typing an exception such as this that clearly identifies the cause, can remain hidden)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.checkNewChild(ASTNode.java:1901)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList.add(ASTNode.java:1269)
```

ASTNode.checkNewChild has a reference equality check, that compares the AST of each node.
Package private access modifier makes it impossible to override.

The only solution that comes to mind is to alter ASTNode in the library

Comment: Getting ASTNode.java is easy & so is editing the code, but recompiling is a problem because there are so many external dependencies. I suppose I should put that in a new question